# How do I bring up the button list?

Tags: ios, swift

Very new to Swift, not sure what the actual term for this is, but I want to bring up one of these lists [Picture of what I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYUPo.jpg)

[image]

What are these lists called and how can I bring one up with a navigation bar button?

Comment: You should review the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/) before posting a question like this.

Comment: you shouldn't ask for tutorials or how to's .... if you have already an implementation, please post it here